# How do custom templates/directives affect load times?

Tags: angularjs

I just learned how to create custom directives with angular today via codeschool and it is fantastic! The way it taught me was to make a directive in my JS file, link it to an html file, then write the tag accordingly in the index.html file which is my main file.

My question is does creating a whole new html file for a custom directive hurt load times on the main page? If you want a reference to the section I'm in, it is shaping up with angular level 4 (custom directives).

Comment: It can affect load times both positively and negatively, depending on how you include your template in the codebase. (you could precompile it and include it with the js, or let angular send an http request to retrieve it)

Comment: Which would be the better way to go about it? I recently installed Grunt and while i have no idea what it does, I believe it compiles all your code into one file (css and js). Would it be best to have one giant JS file (including all the angular bootstrap pre-written stuff, I'll clear out whatever isn't used) or would it be better to just have angular make a request and retrieve it in a different file?

Comment: It depends. If you precompile them and include in JS, the up front load times are longer, but the rendering is faster once it's loaded. If you don't load it up front, the load times are faster, but the rendering may take longer the first time.

Comment: and third alternative is lazy load them into `$templateCache`. Best way is dependent on size of app and app usage

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you precompile the templates directly into your main.js or not.

If you precompile them, your main.js will take longer to load, but, when rendering the view, angular won't need to send an http request to get the template so rendering will happen faster.

If you don't precompile them, the up front load time will be faster, but rendering the view may be slower the first time because angular needs to send an http request to get the template for the first time. after the first load, it will be cached in the template cache.

You could also use a hybrid solution, precompiling things needed for the main entry to your app, and letting angular request the rest as needed.

which one is better is a debate not suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Gotcha, didn't realize there were so many factors (novice dev here). Last thing i want is to start a debate but regardless I appreciate the input, thanks!

Comment: End of the day, the main point is that there are many options, and you'll have to weigh their differences based on your app structure and needs.